# How does Google Docs API handle table span?

Tags: google-docs-api

When table cells are merged in a Google Doc it can be seen as [ColumnSpan/RowSpan](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents#TableCellStyle)

However the documentation doesn't specify how this should be interpreted.

Cells that are hidden by previously spanning cells are still present in the JSON document.

It's not clear whether they are hidden or pushed.

How should cell span be interpreted?

Answer (score 1):

Every cell in a table without spanning cells are represented in the JSON document.

When one cell spans another cell, the hidden cell is still present in the JSON document with text content of "\n".

It's up to the reader to keep track of hidden cells.